# Block level back up to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently in our environment backups are stored to Network Drive using Windows Server Backup and then manually copy these backups to external HDDs. Now we are planning to move these backups to S3. So I searched for a tool which can create backups and block level upload to S3, so that only changed blocks will be uploaded (bandwidth is a concern too) and I came across cloudberry, but it is not affordable. So I decided to proceed with current setup except instead of copy to External HDDs, copy these backups to S3 manually or using scripts. How do I enable versioning in S3 bucket help me to make a setup so that only changes will be get uploaded, after first backup upload to AWS S3?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [AWS Storage Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/)? I think this is essentially what you want, you can access it directly or create a virtual tape library which will show up as a SCSI tape drive in Windows